# Navigating "File Search" results in Eclipse with keyboard shortcuts

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to launch a File Search then navigate the results (jump to next / previous match) without leaving the editor window.

I currently do it like this...

1. Open File Search <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> and search
2. Open results window <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>
3. Show Next Match <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>
4. Switch back to editor <kbd>ENTER</kbd> (jumps to selected line)
5. *Edit code*
6. Switch back to Search results <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>
7. *Goto [3]*

...but obviously this is a bit tedious. Ideally the Show Next Match shortcut would work in the editor window like <kbd>F8</kbd> does in Visual Studio.

I'm using Eclipse Indigo Service Release 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible, however other people want this functionality, and someone has even implemented an example plug-in of how it should be done.

[Here is a blog post about the plug-in](http://www.vogella.de/blog/2010/11/16/next-previous-search-shortcut/)

...and [the bugzilla report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=328460) where the functionality was requested (and the example plug-in attached). Perhaps you should try installing it and adding your voice to the bug?

Comment: Added my comments to the bug report and I'll try the plug-in.

Comment: Site http://www.vogella.de/blog/2010/11/16/next-previous-search-shortcut/ no longer available ?